# python docker container exits immediately upon starting

Tags: centos, python, docker

I am trying to run a python container to be used as a virtual development environment. I am building my own docker image with a custom written `Dockerfile`. The image builds are always successful, but when I run the container off the image, it exits immediately upon starting. I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

My `Dockerfile`:

```
# Creates Python2.7.10 image for a python  dev environemnt on CentOs 7.x

FROM centos:latest

MAINTAINER nmd

# Installs dependencies
RUN yum update -y && \
yum groupinstall development -y && \
yum install -y \
openssl \
openssl-devel \
bzip2-devel \
gcc \
tar \
wget \
zlib-dev \
git \
sudo \
sqlite-devel

# Downloads and installs Python
RUN mkdir /tmp_python && \
cd /tmp_python && \
wget --no-check-certificate https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.10/Python-
2.7.10.tgz && \
tar -zxvf Python-2.7.10.tgz && \
cd /tmp_python/Python-2.7.10 && \
./configure --prefix=/usr/local && \
make && \
make altinstall && \
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

# Installs pip
RUN cd /tmp_python && \
wget --no-check-certificate https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && \
python get-pip.py

# Installs virtualenv
RUN pip install virtualenv

# Creates working directory
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code

# Default command
CMD ["python"]
```

When I do `docker ps -a`, this is what I see:

```
[root@centos python]# docker run -d --name python-dev a9f468205931
[root@centos python]# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             
STATUS                         PORTS               NAMES
c47908801503        a9f468205931        "python"                 34 minutes 
ago      **Exited (0)** 34 minutes ago                          python-dev
                     PORTS               NAMES
```

As you can see, the container already exited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need:

```
docker run -dit --name python-dev a9f468205931
```

`-d`, --detach Run container in background and print container ID

`-i`, --interactive Keep STDIN open even if not attached

`-t`, --tty Allocate a pseudo-TTY

Comment: This worked. Container is now steadily running.